# Connect Wall of Flags: Don't Embarrass Us

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, connect-wall, flags

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7045/fortnightly-topic-challenge-42-wordless-connecting-walls)</sup>

---

K. G. (Knockoff Gladys) surprised me today with a note.

> Hey, bobble!
>
> I took your advice and made a puzzle. Who knew that was the way to get famous nowadays! You have to split these flags into 4 groups of 4. Then find another flag that fits into all of the categories - that’s where I’m going. Yes, yes, it’s dangerous to travel *right now* (and that’s important to remember!). But I’m going to do one of those virtual travel thingies. Anyways. I've attached the flag pictures. I'm sure you and those big-brained PSE folks will solve this in no time!
>
> *-K. G.*

[image: 16 flags]

So, where is K. G. going on their "virtual travel thingy"? I *may* have said Puzzling was really good at this sort of thing. Don't embarrass <s>me</s> us, solve this quick!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the missing flag is:

> [image]
>
>  i.e. the flag of **GERMANY**

The flags depicted are (left to right, top to bottom):

> ANGOLA, OMAN, MANITOBA, FINLAND;
>  KENYA, ROMANIA, DENMARK, FRANCE;
>  POLAND, CAYMAN ISLANDS, GABON, EGYPT;
>  JAPAN, BARBADOS, BOTSWANA, TENNESSEE.

The four connecting groups are:

> 1. **Places containing 'MAN':** O**MAN**, **MAN**ITOBA, RO**MAN**IA, CAY**MAN** ISLANDS.
>
>  2. **Places which have chemical elements named after them:** FRANCE (Francium and Gallium), POLAND (Polonium), JAPAN (Nihonium), TENNESSEE (Tennessine).
>
>  3. **Flags with a horizontal black stripe in the design:** ANGOLA, KENYA, EGYPT, BOTSWANA. (Prompted by @JeremyDover in comments)
>
>  4. **Countries with a female leader:** FINLAND ([Sanna Marin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanna_Marin), PM), DENMARK ([Mette Frederiksen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mette_Frederiksen), PM), GABON ([Rose Raponda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_Christiane_Raponda), PM), BARBADOS ([Mia Mottley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mia_Mottley), PM).

A flag which therefore satisfies all 4 of these groups is:

> Germany's, since (i) GER**MAN**Y contains 'MAN', (ii) the element Germanium is named after Germany, (iii) it includes a black horizontal stripe in its design, and (iv) the current (female) Chancellor of Germany is [Angela Merkel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkel).

<sub>Notes:</sub>

> <sub>I suspect the prominent mention of "*right now* (and that’s important to remember!)" in the flavour text is an indication that something related to **current affairs** (and which may change in the future) is key to the puzzle. With the fourth category focused on **politics** (where leaders may change in elections) I think this hidden hint is satisfied.</sub>
>
>  <sub>Also, there is a hint concealed in the title - the initials of '**D**on't **E**mbarrass **U**s' are '**DEU**', the common 3-letter abbreviation for '**Deutschland**' - the country's name in German!</sub>

Comment: 3 and 4 aren't the intended categories (my 4 is much more specific).

Comment: @bobble Hmmm, ok will rethink on those 2...

Comment: As a hint, rot13(ab synt pbhyq svg vagb nal bs gur bgure guerr pngrtbevrf).

Comment: "LAND" seems to invalidate 3

Comment: Perhaps relevant: rot13(Natbyn, Obgfjnan, Rtlcg, naq Xraln nyy unir n OYNPX fgevcr)

Comment: @JeremyDover Yes, I spotted that one but struggled with the 4 remaining! I figured categories 1 and 2 were too precise to be accidental and had to be included... So it's why  rot13(Tnoba, Oneonqbf, Svaynaq naq Qraznex) go together that I couldn't quite suss...

Comment: @bobble Think I found it now! :)

Comment: Yep, you got it! Checkmark for you :) One final thing, though: the title is hiding a hint.

Comment: Thanks @bobble - nice interpretation of the theme :) EDIT: Oh, and I've just seen what the hint is...!